# Pattern printing using single loop

Tags: java, loops

I have written the code for printing slash using 2 for loops. How can I print the same using only one for loop?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int i,j;char[][] ch=new char[100][100];
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)

    {
        if(i==j)
            ch[i][j]='*';
        else
            ch[i][j]=' ';
        System.out.print(ch[i][j]);

    }
    System.out.println(' ');
}
```

Comment: Can you show what are the result that you want?

Comment: I want to print special characters like / , \,? in star pattern

Comment: Yes - but if you want us to find a different way to get this result - it will be easier if you will show us the results

Comment: \- this character is printed in star pattern.   this is the result i got for my above code. I want similar results for other characters like \ , ? ,||

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] line = new char[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      Arrays.fill(line, ' ');
      line[i] = '*';
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is to use array-based operations (in this case, `fill`) to avoid one of the explicit loops.

Answer (score 2):

Still slower:

```
For(int i = 0; i < width*height; i++) {
  Int x = i%height
  Int y = (i-x)/height
  // Code using ch[x][y]
}
```

Edited via phone :)